# Problems with Qt iterators in QLinkedList

Tags: qt, iterator, qt5

I know I will be asked for a minimal example, but I am not sure to be able to come up with one at all, or it won't be very minimal. But I may still learn valuable knowledge from this discussion.

So I have a series of data items of a given class organized in a QLinkedList. The user is provided with an interface that allows to navigate through this data and edit it. In particular, some of the possible editing actions require multiple entries in the QLinkedList to be modified - for example all subsequent or all previous entries. Items can also be added or removed to the list, and then edited.

In the code, I simply keep an iterator up to date that points to the current data item in the chain, called `m_currentItem`. I then use it to display the data at the current item, loop from the current to the end or to the beginning. I require this iterator to be valid throughout the whole execution and lifetime of the application, even if items are added or removed. When the user presses "next" or "previous" the iterator is simply incremented or decremented. When the user deletes an item in the list (except the last), the iterator then points to the next entry and its content is displayed. When a user adds an item in the list, `m_currentItem` is now made to point to this new item.

This is where things go pretty wrong : On those backwards or forward loops. They often (but not always ...) go over the end condition and continue into unknown data until a major crash ensues. Sometimes it also loops back to the first element in the list (!!!) and then it's an infinite loop for ya.

Here's an example taken from my code, anything obviously wrong ? Anything else I should know about Qt iterators ?

EDIT :

Just learned about reverse iterators ! It seems recommends using them instead of the `--` overloaded operator on standard iterators ! But how do I make `m_currentItems` a reverse iterator ?

Also I read about implicit sharing ... I don't really do anything like that I don't think, but does that go to show that I shouldn't be using long-living iterators like I do ?

```
include <QLinkedList>

struct Member
{
    int memberID;
}

struct Item
{
    /* A map of members, each mapped to an ID */
    QMap<int, Member> m_members;
    QString name;
}

typedef QLinkedList<Item> LinkedItems;

LinkedItems m_items;
LinkedItems::iterator m_currentItem;

...

if(m_currentItem != m_items.end())
{
    for(LinkedItems::iterator iter = m_currentItem+1; iter != m_items.end(); iter++)
    {
        // Do things on *iter
    }
}
```

A more complex implementation : in each linked Items are found Members which contain data, and an ID. It is possible for the user to propagate an ID in all previous items located before an item located (that must itself be located before the current item) that he is asked to choose.

E.g. if we have A-B-C-D-E-F and the user is on E, he can choose to propagate a member ID of E to C and previous items (so A and B, too - but not to D).

Here's the code. Most or all the iterator loops are subject to unexpected behaviors.

```
void renameAllPreviousMembers(int memberIDToPropagate)
{
    /* If first item, then there is no previous altogether */
    if(m_currentItem != m_items.begin())
    {
        if(m_currentItem.m_members.contains(memberIDToPropagate) == false)
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, tr("Rename members in previous items"),
                                          tr("There is no member with the selected ID in the current item."),
                                          QMessageBox::Ok);
            return;
        }

        bool chose_item;
        LinkedItems::iterator itemIter;
        QStringList previousItems;
        QStringList previousItemsBetterOrder;
        QMap<QString, LinkedItems::iterator> previousItemsMap;

        previousItemsMap.clear();

        /* Find all previous items and store them in a QStringList and a map between those strings and actual items */
        std::cout << "Search previous items : " << std::flush;
        for(itemIter = m_items.begin();
            itemIter != m_currentItem;
            itemIter++)
        {
            /* Possibly add conditions on some items that we do not want to apply values to. */
            std::cout << itemIter->name << ", " << std::flush;
            previousItems << itemIter->name;
            previousItemsMap.insert(itemIter->name, itemIter);
        }
        std::cout << "finished." << std::endl << std::flush;

        QStringList::reverse_iterator riter;

        for(riter = previousItems.rbegin(); riter != previousItems.rend(); riter++)
        {
            previousItemsBetterOrder << *riter;
        }

        QString name_previous_item = QInputDialog::getItem(nullptr,
                                                      QString("Previous item"),
                                                      QString("Previous item to start from : "),
                                                      previousItemsBetterOrder, 0, false, &chose_item);

        if(!chose_item)
        {
            return;
        }

        /* Decode chosen previous item by retrieving it in the map */
        LinkedItems::iterator chosenPrevIter = previousItemsMap.value(name_previous_item);

        bool chose_member;

        /* Find all existing IDs in previous item */

        QStringList previousIDs;

        QMap<int, Member>::const_iterator memberIter;

        /* Retrieve all members from the chosen previous item */

        std::cout << "Search IDs in chosen previous item : " << std::flush;
        for(memberIter = chosenPrevIter->m_members.begin(); memberIter != chosenPrevIter->m_members.end(); memberIter++)
        {
            previousIDs << QString("%1").arg(QString::number(memberIter->ID));
            std::cout << memberIter->memberID << ", " << std::flush;
        }
        std::cout << "finished." << std::endl << std::flush;

        /* If no member then no lunch */
        if(previousIDs.size() == 0)
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, tr("Rename previous member"),
                                          tr("There are no members in the selected previous item."),
                                          QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Ok);
            return;
            std::cout << "Rename previous members finished with no members in chosen previous item." << std::endl << std::flush;
        }

        QString string_member_id_from_previous = QInputDialog::getItem(nullptr,
                                                      QString("Previous member number"),
                                                      QString("Member ID from previous item to be used : "),
                                                      previousIDs, 0, false, &chose_member);
        if(chose_member)
        {
            int member_id_from_previous = string_member_id_from_previous.toInt();


            /* Update member ID at and before chosen previous item */

            std::cout << "Update member ID before chosen previous item : " << std::flush;
            for(itemIter = chosenPrevIter;
                itemIter != m_items.begin();
                itemIter--)
            {
                std::cout << itemIter->name << std::flush;
                if(itemIter->m_members.contains(member_id_from_previous))
                {
                    /* Take and reinsert to new ID. */
                    std::cout << "+" << std::flush;
                    itemIter->m_members.insert(memberIDToPropagate, itemIter->m_members.take(member_id_from_previous));
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Do nothing. */
                }
                std::cout << ", " << std::flush;
            }
            std::cout << "finished." << std::endl << std::flush;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Do nothing. */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, tr("Apply to previous members"),
                             tr("This is the first item. There are no previous items."),
                             QMessageBox::Ok);

    }
    std::cout << "Apply to previous members finished." << std::endl << std::flush;
}
```

Comment: We really need a minimal and complete example: we need to know how you modify `m_currentItem`.

Comment: The loop shown doesn't handle the case where `m_currentItem == m_items.end()` to begin with.

Comment: Yes the case `m_currentItem == m_items.end()` is handled